# Mocha Test of Mongoose Model yields error with 'then'

Tags: mongoose, mocha.js

I'm running early tests of an API and the error should be obvious but I'm getting batty eyed looking at the same code for 45 minutes.

Here is the error

```
Creating User document find or create a twitter user:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Here is the test. The error is with the line **.then(user=> {...}**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const userController = require('../controllers/usersController');

describe('Creating User document', () => {
    it('find or create a twitter user', (done) => {
            userController.findOrCreateHelper({
                username : 'testuser', 
                displayName : 'testUserDisplay', 
                id : 111000100, 
                provider : 'Twitter'
                })
                .then(user => {
                    console.log('*** Error in this .then bracket ***', user)
                    assert(user === 'testuser')
                    assert(user.id === 111000100)
                    done()
                }).catch(error => console.error(error))
    })
```

Here is the controller

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/userModel');

exports.findUser = ({id}) => {
    return User.findOne({id})
}

exports.createUser = ({username, displayName, id, provider}) => {
    return User.create( {username, displayName, id, provider })
}

exports.findOrCreateHelper = (provider) => {
    exports.findUser({id})
        .then(user => {
            if ( !user ) {
                exports.createUser(provider)
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Found the problem ... details below

Answer (score 0):

exports.findOrCreateHelper needs to "return exports.findUser({...}}..." like below:

```
exports.findOrCreateHelper = (provider) => {
    return exports.findUser({id})
        .then(user => {
            if ( !user ) {
                exports.createUser(provider)
            }
        })
}
```